# How to hide html tags from textbox?

Tags: php, html, css, textbox, tags

I use php to read txt file to textbox and I would like to hide html tags (check the picture) in textbox, not delete, just hide and don't show the users.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXbKr.jpg

Comment: you can't hide content from a textbox without deleting it. it's a plain text input. 
to achieve that, i'd recommend using a `<div>` that can render HTML within it, without loosing the tags.

Comment: Do you want to hide HTML tags functionality also?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you're looking for is a wysiwyg editor.

Comment: more info needed, what are you trying to do, how do you handle the data in your backend?

Comment: how would you like the text to handle deletion of any kind of element?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide parts of a text box value while still having them in the data.

You could look at using [a content editable div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) instead (these are generally used as the foundation of so-called wysiwyg editors) and convert `<br>` to `<span style="display: none;">&lt;br&gt;</span>` for use inside it.

You'd then have to remove the spans when you pulled the data back out of the div though.